# How often are CRLs checked?

Tags: list, authentication, certificate, ca

Are Certificate Revocation Lists checked everytime a client receives a certificate? Or does it happen just the first time, and then again when the CRL is updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, a client will download a CRL only when it encounters a certificate signed by a CA (certificate authority) whose CRL it does not have, or whose CRL has expired. This assumes that the client checks CRLs at all.

How often, or even *if*, a certificate is checked against a CA's CRL is up to the client.  The CRL is a rather old technology and is being replaced by OCSP, OCSP stapling, and "pin lists". For example, Google's Chrome browser and the Firefox browser do not download CRLs at all (although Chrome can be manually configured to download CRLs).

The CRL itself will indicate when it will next be updated, but it is up to the client to go and get the update.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering! 
I know CRL are pretty old, this is just for didactic purposes :) Thanks again for clearing my mind!!